# Why does my latex src code block ignore exports header arguments

Tags: org-export, latex, html, header-line

GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2

Org-mode version 8.3.5

At some point in the past I could put down a block like this

```
#+begin_src latex :exports results :results {latex|html}
\begin{equation}
a = 1 + b
\end{eqation}
#+end_src
```

For either html or latex and make it export to the corresponding format.
This functionality have for some reason disappeared and now it exports the src block as a code block instead of the results that exports to nice native latex or html math and rendered that way.

I find it convenient to be able to do this, for a number of reasons, so it would be nice if there was a way to make this work again.

Comment: This is how I did it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wvxvw/introduction-to-data-structures/master/assignment-11/assignment.org (see `by-backend` macro). The commented out version is the one I used with some older version of Org.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For some reason this doesn't seem to do anything for me. Even starting from a fresh slate with -q doesn't yield and output from my code block with a header from  your example and a macro defined.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, just making sure: you evaluated the code with the macro (for example you `C-c C-c` on the code block with the macro). You then used `#+HEADER: :results (by-backend (pdf "latex") (t "raw"))` in your latex code block. The results were actually produced, but without change (rather than, for example, Org exporter dying silently, while leaving the results from the previous export).

Comment: Yeah, I did this but after further investigation it seems like my config is to blame. Haven't found the faulty code yet but I have to backpadle for blaming orgmode changes. Thanks for your answer @wvxvw.

Comment: Turns out I carelessly set the variable `(setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)` which according to the documentation disregards all header arguments. Looks like more than just this issue just got solved for me... Not sure if I should delete this question or rewrite it to be more relevant.

Comment: Why not post your own answer? This seems like it could trip someone else too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I carelessly set the variable

```
(setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)
```

which according to the documentation disregards all header arguments:

> Switch controlling code evaluation during export.
>   When set to nil no code will be evaluated as part of the export
>   process and no header argumentss will be obeyed.  When set to
>   ‘inline-only’, only inline code blocks will be executed.  Users
>   who wish to avoid evaluating code on export should use the header
>   argument ‘:eval never-export’.

After setting this to `t` I could export as expected.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.